# Error: no such file

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I was able to download IDLE. I chmod  to make it executable. but whenever I run the the .py file. I get Error: no such file at the beginning of each line. It runs fine in the module for IDLE but when I try to run in terminal I encounter this problem.

> ~/Desktop/PythonScripts# ./calculator.py Error: no such file "Welcome
>   to my Calculator Program." Error: no such file "You will be able to do
>   basic calculations." Error: no such file "Such as addition,
>   subtraction, multiplication and division." Error: no such file ":For
>   addition press 1: " Error: no such file ":For subtraction press 2: "
>   Error: no such file ":For multiplication press 3: " Error: no such
>   file ":For division press 4: "

I would like to know how to fix this please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add python location at the beginning of your script? If you run

```
which python
```

It will give you the location something like

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Add this at the beginning of your script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: That seemed like an easy fix '#!/usr/bin/python' fixed it right away.
Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it fixed the issue.